# R programming in RStudio on Windows 10: command prompt > disappearing

Tags: r, windows-10

I'm doing some very basic commands in RStudio (in Windows 10), and suddenly/randomly the command prompt ">" disappeared. This is not the first time this has happened for me. Pressing escape, enter, or anything else doesn't get me back the >. Moreover, when I try to close RStudio, it just stays on "quitting r session" and never closes. I tried to embed a screen shot of the console I'm seeing, but I'm not sure if it worked. If anyone can help me with this issue (being able to get back the > and execute commands again) or direct me to another post where this was addressed, I would really appreciate it (otherwise I have to restart my whole system every time to fix it). [image: Screenshot of the console I'm seeing]

Comment: just kill rstudio not your whole system. what commands were you doing before this?

Comment: The problem is I can't quit/kill RStudio--it just doesn't work, keeps Rstudio open, but with the message "quitting r session" the whole time. Beforehand I was just doing some very simple commands--it might have just been summary(cty), str(cty), or nrow(cty), where cty is my data file. I doubt it has something to do with a specific command--it's happened to me before and usually at a random time. I just don't know why I can't regain the > and need to always restart.